# How do I use the request.security_lower_tf(symbol, timeframe, expression) function when the expression argument uses strategy.opentrades.* functions?

Tags: request, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to use the `request.security_lower_tf()` function with an expression that uses a variable declared using

```
strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1).
```

I've tried:

```
entryprice = na
if (some condition) 
   entryprice := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
```

This still gives an error though.

I need a way to use the entry price of the most recent open trade in the `request*` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `strategy.opentrades.*` function calls in `request.security_lower_tf()` functions or define mutable variables with them.

Instead, get the values you need from the lower timeframe using the `request.security_lower_tf()` function and do any calculations with those retrieved values by cycling through the elements in the return array.

For example:

```
float lowsArray = request.security_lower_tf(symbol=, timeframe=, expression = low)
```

Then:

```
lowsArray.get(index=a) - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
```